# Equivalent of `ed.copy` in `tensorflow_probability.edward2`

Tags: tensorflow, bayesian, edward, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to change my code from `edward` to `tensorflow_probability.edward2`. The issue is that, whenever I define a posterior distribution, I use `a_post = ed.copy(a, {u: qu}, scope='a_post')` but `.copy` API seems no longer available:

`module 'tensorflow_probability.python.edward2' has no attribute 'copy'`

What's the `tensorflow_probability` way of doing the same operation?

Answer (score 1):

In edward, copy depended on unsupported TF graph-walking and copying. In edward2, the approach is based on tracing, using 'interceptors'. Check out https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/deep_exponential_family.py for an example of VI using the 'tape' interceptor.

Update: this one might be a simpler and/or more familiar (LDA) example: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/latent_dirichlet_allocation_edward2.py